# HighMaps: Change the size/width of ColorAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

Is there any way to change the width of ColorAxis?

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.11.0/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/mapdata/custom/world-lowres

```
colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        width:300     //something like this?
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem using symbolWidth attribute of legend.

```
legend:{
    symbolWidth:300
}
```